# Can't change texture quality

Tags: steam, path-of-exile

I just downloaded Path of Exile via Steam.

I looked forward to the video settings, and I found that the texture quality is locked to medium (meaning that I can't change it).

Is there a way to change it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try forcing it from your `Documents\My Games\Path of Exile\production_Config.ini` by changing `texture_quality` under `[DISPLAY]`.

Comment: I want to mention that I also had to run notepad with administrator privileges to save the file properly.